# jenkins failed during night build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Like everyday I run night job in jenkins and I didn't had any problem recently with jenkins.
But when I logged in today I saw that the job was stuck. I tried to login to jenkins and I got this issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.User#properties for class hudson.model.User
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:208)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:135)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:161)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:102)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:898)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:887)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:860)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:182)
    at hudson.model.User.save(User.java:504)
    at hudson.model.User.addProperty(User.java:227)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUserDetail.updateUserInfo(ActiveDirectoryUserDetail.java:109)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:296)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:193)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:137)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:122)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:200)
    at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:74)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.MyViewsProperty#views for class hudson.model.MyViewsProperty
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:208)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:135)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:161)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:102)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:217)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:204)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.View#properties for class hudson.model.AllView
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:208)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:135)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:161)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:102)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:217)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:204)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : No space left on device
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.write(QuickWriter.java:49)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.writeText(PrettyPrintWriter.java:275)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.writeAttributeValue(PrettyPrintWriter.java:223)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.addAttribute(PrettyPrintWriter.java:218)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.WriterWrapper.addAttribute(WriterWrapper.java:41)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:195)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.flush(AtomicFileWriter.java:90)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:75)
    ... 98 more`
```

I cannot run any jobs on my jenkins now. Can someone help me?

Comment: See `Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device`.

Comment: issue has been solved thanks engineer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to throw back "No space left on device".

What environment are you running Jenkins from? a VM?

If so check to see if there is enough space left for a build to run. Had this issue previously.

Remember whenever a build is run it saves to a folder. It would be good practice to implement something that after x amount of builds they will be deleted.

Comment: yea the folder where it saved the jobs xml was full so it caused issue login in and running jobs on server .  i cleaned some jobs history and its working now.

Comment: about the x amount , i have already implemented that it would be delete after 90 days , but seems i have done extra job recently that it filled it up .

Comment: @IbrahimShalhoub you would be suprised how fast your memory gets taken up while running Jenkins jobs.

Comment: i know i have vm with 256GB , since i added more servers on jenkins my memory was taken so fast .